# Creating a bound search text box

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form named `RMA Information` bound to a table that has multiple controls and a subform. The form is bound to table [RMAMaster]. The field name in question is `RMANbr`. The field is bound to the [rma_nbr] field of the [RMAMaster] table. The [rma_nbr] field is Indexed and cannot contain duplicates.  The table DOES have it's own [ID] field that is auto increment and cannot contain duplicates.

I would like a user to be able to select the `RMANbr` field on the form, type a new value, press enter, and the bound form will go to that record that they typed, or display a MsgBox if it's not found.

I had the following in the "After Update" Event of the `RMANbr` text box, but it is not working:

```
Private Sub RMANbr_AfterUpdate()
  If (Me.RMANbr & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    rs.FindFirst "[rma_nbr]=" & Me.RMANbr
    If rs.NoMatch Then
        Response = MsgBox("Sorry, no such record was found.", vbOKOnly)
    Else
        Me.Recordset.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
  End If
  rs.Close
End Sub
```

However it fails with the error messages:

> Run-time error '3426': This action was cancelled by an associated
>   object

Hitting debug on this error message points me to the line `Me.Recordset.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark`

Whether or not I click End or Debug on the above the following error message is still produced:

`The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again`

So it appears that Access is trying to save the record with the changed RMANbr, but I don't want it to do that. I would like the RMANbr field to remain a reference to the currently viewed RMA Record, but also use it so that users can "jump" immediately to a specific record if they enter in the RMANbr.

Comment: The seachfield has to be unbound, else it tries to insert the searched value that already exists (thats what a bound field does).

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there was a way to cancel that action by using a bit of vba.

Comment: Not recommended, but you can use the BeforeUpdate Event and set `Cancel = True`to prevent updates. Don't forget `Me.Undo`on Form_Close()`.